# Can't import firestore and firebase in angular 8 for an auth system

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to implement firestore/firebase functionalities for implementing google OAuth signin but it keeps saying that firebase is not imported:

[image: those are the errors that i'm getting]

CODE:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

4 import { User, auth } from 'firebase/app';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:74 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

2 import { auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection-group/collection-group.d.ts:2:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts:2:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/document/document.d.ts:5:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

5 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:8:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

8 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:2:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/auth.service.ts:4:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

4 import { auth } from "firebase/app";
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

WHAT I TRIED:

i tried to reinstall @angular/fire,
i tried to change 'firebase/app' to './firebase/app',
i tried finding a solution here on StackOverflow but nothing.

Thanks for any answers!

tried to: install angular firebase but:
it says this

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.0 and node@11.13.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node' 
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/11.13.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-25-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v67"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v11.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v67' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1001:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-25-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v67' (1)
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 <9 || ^9.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 <9 || ^9.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=6.0.0 <9 || ^9.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=6.0.0 <9 || ^9.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.2.1 requires a peer of firebase@>= 5.5.7 <7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.24.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-16T13_45_44_371Z-debug.log
```

command ran in sudo su by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install this:

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

Add Firebase config to your environment

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: 'Api_key',
        authDomain: 'domain',
        databaseURL: '-------',
        projectId: '------',
        storageBucket: '',
        messagingSenderId: 'hdhdhhdhd',
        appId: 'didkdkdkkd'
    }
};
```

Then in the app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
```

Add to import[] and your config from the environment

```
imports: [
        ...,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
]
```

Then import it in your service

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
```

then use

```
  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install firebase as well

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```